# labels customisation in line chart using highcharts

Tags: reactjs, charts, highcharts, linechart, react-functional-component

I am using line chart, where I have added plot bands ranges. I want to return those labels of y-axis which are present in plot bands.

```
labels: {
formatter: function () {
if ([-12, -10, 0.0, 6.5, 10, 20].includes(this.value)) {
return this.value;
}
return "";
},
},
```

I have added this labels object to y-axis

And also I am unable to set min and max value to y-axis
max: 20,
min: -12,

And there is extra white space added between x-axis and chart which I don't want

https://jsfiddle.net/bhagyeshbodhe/5x8cypqg/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use `tickPositions` instead of `labels.formatter`. For example:

```
tickPositions: [-12, -10, 0.0, 6.5, 10, 20]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vz5ychx0/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions